# comparing elements in list of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, multidimensional-array, list-comparison

I basically have a list of lists like this:
    `[['sd', 'pd', 'od'], ['sd', 'pd1', 'od2'], ['sd2', 'pd2', 'od']]`
and I want the output to be `['sd pd od ; pd1 od2 .', 'sd2 pd2 od .']`
So, I want to compare the first element of each list with each other and if they are the same, I want to leave out the first element (that occurs in the second list).

Here is my code which doesn't work as it compares the elements too much and I don't know why.

```
def simplistic(triples):
base = []
for x in triples:
    for y in triples:
        if x[0] == y[0]:
            base.append((x[:],y[1],y[2]))
print(base)
```

The output of this code is:

```
[(['sd', 'pd', 'od'], 'pd', 'od'), (['sd', 'pd', 'od'], 'pd1', 'od2'), (['sd', 'pd1', 'od2'], 'pd', 'od'), (['sd', 'pd1', 'od2'], 'pd1', 'od2'), (['sd2', 'pd2', 'od'], 'pd2', 'od')]
```

Comment: what if the input is `[['sd', 'pd', 'od'], ['sd', 'pd1', 'od2'], ['sd2', 'pd2', 'od'],['sd2', 'pd2', 'od3']]`. what is the desired output?

Comment: it would be ['sd pd od ; pd1 od2 .', 'sd2 pd2 od ; pd2 od3.']

Comment: I have updated my answer, check if it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you question is a little unclear, try this and check is it ok or not.

```
bad_list = []
f=''
for i,s in enumerate(l):
    if s[0] == l[i-1][0] or s[0] in bad_list:
        f = f + ' '.join(s[1:])
        bad_list.append(s[0])           
    else:
        f = f + ' '.join(s)
    f = f+ ' ;'
f = [f[:-1] + '.']
```

The `f` will be your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for grouping the lists based on the first element, you can do this easily using `defaultdict`

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> triples =  [['sd', 'pd', 'od'], ['sd', 'pd1', 'od2'], ['sd2', 'pd2', 'od']]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> 
>>> for k,*l in triples:
...     d[k].extend(l)
...
>>> res = [[k]+l for k,l in d.items()]
>>> print(res)
[['sd', 'pd', 'od', 'pd1', 'od2'], ['sd2', 'pd2', 'od']]
```